# cut(1) delimeter error with system(3)

Tags: c, system, cut, gnupg

I try to parse a gpg key list with some bunch of shell command. First i use grep, then cut.

Here, the command i want to launch with system(3) :

```
cut -d$'\n' -f2 /root/grep_output > /root/key_output
```

(^ this command work in shell)

Whatever i tried (included put some ), i've always got this error after system execution:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

I guess i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to do? what does grep_output contain?

Comment: Yes, you've done something wrong. If you show us your code that calls `system ()`, we might even be able to tell you *what* you've done wrong.

Comment: One possible clue: `system()` (on UNIX-like systems) invokes the command using `/bin/sh`, which may or may not support the `$'\n'` syntax.